# Set custom property to all form objects in nested reactive forms structure

Tags: angular, forms, nested, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem with a complex angular application.
Currently, I have a big nested angular reactive forms structure with one "main" FormGroup that contains multi `FormGroup` / `FormArrays` / `FormControls` inside them.

As Example:

```
 FormGroup: {  
    FormControl: {}  
    FormGroup: {FormGroup: {FormControl...,   FormControl...}}  
    FormArray: [FormGroup {...}, FormGroup{...}]    
...  
}
```

Now I want to add a custom `FormControl` / `Property` to **all** children of the big main Form. In my case, it would be like "`Read-Only: true`".

One solution would be to give all child elements (Forms) in HTML the parent form as `@Input`, so I must only add a property to the parent-form.
But maybe there is a smoother way to do this that I cannot think of.

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions or any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A FormGroup can be iterate over the controls -well they are objects, but you can use Object.keys- you can use a recursive function, e.g.

```
setEnabled(formGroup,value)
  {
     Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(x=>{
       const gr=formGroup.get(x)
       if (gr.controls) //if has controls is a formGroup (or a FormArray)
            this.setEnabled(gr,value)
        else
        {
          console.log(gr.value) //<--show the value
          if (value)
            gr.enable()
          else
            gr.disable();
        }
     })
  }
```